# Access the first element of a sorted list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

Below is the original table:

```
identifier            comments_count
2353962646372849000        4153
2353962646372849028        6102
2342365172189273063        3936
2353962646372849567        5202
2342365172189273168        3076
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({

    'identifier': [2353962646372849000, 2353962646372849028, 2342365172189273063, 2353962646372849567 , 2342365172189273168],

    'comments_count': [4153, 6102, 3936, 5202, 3076],
})
```

I would like to access the first element of the dfsorted.identifier, which is a sorted list.

The query should have an output of `'2353962646372849028'`.

`dfsorted = df.sort_values('comments_count',ascending=False)`

```
identifier            comments_count
2353962646372849028        6102
2353962646372849567        5202
2353962646372849000        4153
2342365172189273063        3936
2342365172189273168        3076
```

The query

```
dfsorted['identifier'][0]
```

however keeps returning `'2353962646372849000'` (the first element of the identifier before the sorting).
How to fix the issue?

Comment: Use `dfsorted = df.sort_values('comments_count',ascending=False, ignore_index=True)`

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```
dfsorted.iloc[0,:]['identifier']
```

or simpler:

```
dfsorted.iloc[0,0]
```

result:

```
2353962646372849028
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dfsorted = df.sort_values('comments_count', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Use this to reset the indexes :D

Sorting a List doesn't update the indexes, if you print the Table you will see the indexes weren't renewed. By using `reset_index(drop=True)` you create new indexes and drop the old ones. If you leave out `drop=True` it saves the old indexes in an extra column.

Answer (score 0):

```
dfs=df.groupby('comments_count', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1, columns=['identifier'])).reset_index(level=1, drop=1)
```

The reset index will work fine, the result come as you wish:

```
2342365172189273168
```